# Need help using IVT in application

Tags: calculus

Explain how $$\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})=1-x$$

has at least one real solution.

I understand that IVT requires you to have the endpoints.

I know that $-1\leq \sin x \leq 1$

So $-1 \leq \sin(\frac{\pi x}{2}) \leq 1$

If $f(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi x}{2})-1+x$

$f(-1)=-1+1-(-1)=1>0$

$f(1)=1-1+1=1>0$

But I need one of them to be less than 0. What did I do wrong and how  do I solve this?

Comment: Well, $f(-1)\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

On $[0,1]$, $f(0)=-1$ while $f(1)=1$.

Can you finish now?

By the way, $f(-1)=-3$.

Comment: oh okay, so then is my answer correct?

Comment: You have $f(-1)=1$, which is not correct.  And if it were correct, the IVT would not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Let, f(x) = sin(πx/2) - 1+X
f(1) = 1
f(0) = -1
By Intermediate value property there must be a real root in (0,1).
By the way,
f(-1) = -3
You have done a mistake by doing ' -(-1) ' . It should be '(-1)'.
Look it carefully.

Comment: why is your interval (0,1) and not (-1,1)?

Comment: (0,1) is contained in (-1,1). So, There is no problem to say (0,1) instead of(-1,1) .f(-1) = -3, f(0) =-1  ,f keeps same sign on (-1,0) . That's why I said it has a real root in (0,1).

Comment: so will my answer be correct if i use (-1,1) instead of (0,1)?

Comment: Your answer is also correct. just make correction ,f(-1) = 3.